# Like button redirects to login page php

Tags: php

Im working on designing a basic social media site, and my like button always redirects me to the login page instead of actually 'liking' the post. Below is the code that I am using. Any help would be amazing.

```html
<?php
include('./classes/Login.php');

$isfollowing = False;
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
 header('Location: login.php');
} else {
 $users = $_SESSION['username'];
}
 
$username = $_GET['u'];

if(DB::query("SELECT username, fname FROM users WHERE username='$username'")) {
 $user = $username;
  
 $userid = DB::query('SELECT id FROM users WHERE username=:username', array(':username'=>$username))[0]['id'];
 $followerid = $users;
  
 if(isset($_POST['post'])) {
  $userid = DB::query('SELECT id FROM users WHERE username=:username', array(':username'=>$username))[0]['id'];
  $postbody = $_POST['postbody'];
  if (strlen($postbody) > 300 || strlen($postbody) < 3) {
   
   die('Invalid Length.');
   
  }

   DB::query('INSERT INTO posts VALUES (\'\', :postbody, NOW(), :userid, 0)', array(':postbody'=>$postbody, ':userid'=>$userid));  
 }
 
 if(isset($_POST['like'])) {
  
 DB::query('UPDATE posts SET likes = likes+1 where user_id=:user');
DB::query('INSERT INTO post_likes VALUES (\'\', :postid, :userid)', array(':postid'=>$postId, ':userid'=>$followerid)); 
 
 }
 
 
 if(isset($_POST['unlike'])) {
  
 DB::query('UPDATE posts SET likes = likes+1 where user_id=:user');
DB::query('DELETE FROM post_likes WHERE post_id=:postid AND user_id=:userid', array(':postid'=>$postId, ':userid'=>$followerid));
 
 }
 $dbposts = DB::query('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id=:userid ORDER BY id DESC', array(':userid'=>$userid));
 $posts = "";
 foreach($dbposts as $p) {
  
  if(!DB::query('SELECT post_id FROM post_lilkes WHERE post_id=:postid AND user_id=:userid', array(':postid'=>$p['id'], ':userid'=>$users))) {
  $posts .= htmlspecialchars($p['body'])."
  <form action='profile.php?u=".$username."&postid=".$p['id']." method='post'>
   <input type='submit' name='like' value='Like!'>
   <span>".$p['likes']."</span>
   </form>
 <hr /></br />";
  } else {
   $posts .= htmlspecialchars($p['body'])."
   <form action='profile.php?u=".$username."&postid=".$p['id']." method='post'>
   <input type='submit' name='unlike' value='Unlike'>
   <span>" .$p['likes']."</span>
   </form>
 <hr /></br />";
  }
 } 
 
} else {
 header('Location: login.php');
}
?>
```

After running `var_dump($_SESSION, $_POST); exit;` I get the following output: `array(1) { ["username"]=> string(7) "ankoryx" } array(0) { }`

Comment: Perhaps it's because the session variable you set is called `$_SESSION['userid']`? You use `$users` as the `$followerid` and then use that as the `user_id` of the `post_likes` table. To debug, you can try adding `var_dump($_SESSION, $_POST); exit;` after the call to `session_start();`. If you do, please edit the output into the question (please remove any passwords/non-local ip addresses/etc-information first).

Comment: Also, you call `DB::query('UPDATE posts SET likes = likes+1 where user_id=:user');` but don't pass an array with the value of `:user`. Another thing, even for "unlike" you use `likes = likes + 1`. Should that be `likes = likes - 1`?